# Shortcut key for scrolling inside a terminal

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, scrolling

What is the shortcut key for scrolling inside a terminal?

If I hit the <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow or <kbd>PageUp</kbd> or <kbd>PageDown</kbd>, it will only traverse through command history, not let me traverse the previous part displayed in the terminal.

Especially when I run Matlab in a terminal, I have the same problem.

My OS is Ubuntu.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd>/<kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> will scroll in gnome-terminal and Terminal.

Comment: +1 Thanks! How about making up/down arrow keys to work?

Comment: Are Shift + uparrow and Shift + downarrow supposed not to work?

Comment: But be sure you don't have them bound as hotkeys. Also, check the terminal preferences.

Comment: I've never run across any terminal which didnt support at least the SHIFT PGUP/PGDN combo. The actual console (tty1, tty2, etc) even supports it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this can't be customized: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/-/issues/6777

Answer (score 19):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>
for gnome-terminal single line up/down